# How to make a data frame combining different regression results in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am running some regression models to predict performance.
After running the models I created a variable to see the predictions (y_pred_* are lists with 2567 values):

```
y_pred_LR = regressor.predict(X_test)

y_pred_SVR = regressor2.predict(X_test)

y_pred_RF = regressor3.predict(X_test)
```

the types of these prediction lists are Array of float64, while the y_test is a DataFrame.

I wanted to create a table with the results, I tried some different ways, calling as list, trying to convert, trying to select as values, and I did not succeed so far, any one could help?

My last trial was like below:

```
comparison = pd.DataFrame({'Real': y_test, LR':y_pred_LR,'RF':y_pred_RF,'SVM':y_pred_SVM})
```

In this case the DataFrame is created but the values don´t appear.

Additionally, I would like to create two new rows with the mean and standard deviation of results and this row should be located at beginning (or first row) of the Data Frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

real = np.array([2] * 10).reshape(-1,1)
y_pred_LR = np.array([0] * 10)
y_pred_SVR = np.array([1] * 10)
y_pred_RF = np.array([5] * 10)

real = real.flatten()

comparison = pd.DataFrame({'real':real,'y_pred_LR':y_pred_LR,'y_pred_SVR':y_pred_SVR,"y_pred_RF":y_pred_RF})

Mean = comparison.mean(axis=0)
StD = comparison.std(axis=0)

Mean_StD = pd.concat([Mean,StD],axis=1).T

result = pd.concat([Mean_StD,comparison],ignore_index=True)

print(result)
```

Comment: As my list is an array of float64 I got the error: Data must be 1-dimensional. Data Frame from pandas is not recognizing prediction as a list. The prediction size is (2567,), the y_test is (2567,1).

Comment: In that case you need to flatten() your y_test array